# How do I force drop expiry-release partitioned tables in GridDB?

Tags: griddb

I have a container I made as seen here:

```
Database    : public
Name        : RAWLOG_agent_tests
Type        : COLLECTION
Partition ID: 78
DataAffinity: -
Partitioned : true
Partition Type           : INTERVAL
Partition Column         : ts
Partition Interval Value : 30
Partition Interval Unit  : DAY
Expiration Type      : PARTITION
Expiration Time      : 30
Expiration Time Unit : DAY

Columns:
No  Name                  Type            CSTR  RowKey
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0  ts                    TIMESTAMP(3)    NN
 1  hostname              STRING
 2  logtype               STRING
 3  value                 STRING
 4  path                  STRING
```

I made a mistake though and would like to drop the table, but when I try to do it in the shell, it just gives me an error:

```
D20357: This operation on the partitioned container is not allowed.
```

This looks to be a design thing and it isn't the end of the world for me to just rename my container, but I suppose I'm more curious at this point as to the proper procedure here.